# How to do a two way sync with an SQL database and IndexedDB?

Tags: javascript, postgresql, rest, indexeddb

I understand how to sync from IndexedDB to the SQL DB. However, I don't understand how I can sync from the SQL DB to IndexedDB, as far as I know there are no REST API's in JavaScript. If anyone knows of a way I can do this please let me know.

Thanks.

Comment: What do you mean by "IndexedDB", exactly? (Are you referring to the browser-based store)

Comment: Why would you want to do that? (You probably shouldn't) http://xyproblem.info

Comment: @Dai IndexedDB is a client side NoSQL database. Similar to LocalStorage.

Comment: @D.Pardal I am making an offline first app, so if someone does something on their offline device they can sync to the SQL db when they come back online and then someone else can sync theirs on a different device and retrieve that data.

Comment: Syncing databases is really hard. The best thing you can do is to make a request that responds with the records serialized to something like JSON, and then store it tin IndexedDB, but you probably don't want to sync your whole database.

Comment: @D.Pardal Yes I think that's what I'll have to do. I think sending a timestamp in a POST request which represents the last sync, and querying all new data created after that time is the best approach.